# VBScript leaves phantom processes running; How to get rid of them?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am doing some automation with vbscript and everytime I run the script, it leaves the process "EXCEL.EXE" running. How do I prevent that?

Code:

```
Set oFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set objExcel = createObject("Excel.Application")
set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.open("C:\test\test.xlsx")

for each sheet in objWorkbook.worksheets
wscript.echo(sheet.name)
set objSheet = sheet

next 

set objSheet = Nothing
set objworkbook = Nothing
set objExcel = Nothing
Set oFs = Nothing
```

How do I prevent EXCEL.exe from continuing to run after my script exits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to close Excel as well. Just replace your code after Next with the following.

```
set objSheet = Nothing
'Tells workbook to close without saving changes.
objWorkbook.Close false
set objworkbook = Nothing
'Tells Excel Application to quit.
objExcel.Quit
set objExcel = Nothing
Set oFs = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you. Simple and easy. Is there a site with all the methods and members for "Excel.Application"?

Comment: Here's one for [Excel 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb210077(v=office.12).aspx) the links on the left will give you access to pages about each property, event, and method.

Comment: msdn.microsoft.com is the site with the information for the Excel object model.

Comment: Exactly as Sorceri said. When I'm searching for something about Office like in your example, I would search "Excel.Application MSDN" Generally the top links will be official Microsoft documentation.